# how to make query by date in access 2013?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I made access application and i  have query build on date criteria 
this is my query

```
Set sales = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select *  From sales where action_date = #" & date_actions & "#")
```

I change the date in windows to  `dd/mm/yyyy`

But when i try to run this query nothing happens
But when i change it to default  `MM/d/yyyy`
It run correctly

How to solve this problem? Please, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I suggest use this format:  `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

You can convert your date as follows:

```
Format(date_actions, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

Then your statement will be:

```
Set ftm_date = Format(date_actions, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
Set sales = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From sales where action_date = #" & ftm_date & "#")
```

Comment: Access/JET does not support this format. Your answer might be applicable for a SQL DB. You could refer to my answer for the right Access format.

Comment: @PaulFrancis Incorrect. ACE/Jet certainly does support the unambiguous `yyyy-mm-dd` format in Date/Time literals.

Answer (score 0):

JET engine deals date in American format, not the regular DD/MM/YYYY HH:NN:SS. So you need to format the dates accordingly.

```
Set sales = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * " & _
                                    "FROM " & _
                                    "sales " & _
                                    "WHERE action_date = " & Format(date_actions, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"))
```

Hope this helps.